# Problem reading the value of \@itemdepth

Tags: lists

I am a new LaTeX user.  I am trying to format a generalized list.  I have mush of it working.  I am trying to get the value of the `\@itemdepth` so I can determine the amount of indenting being used at the current depth.  I am getting an error that references the `\@itemdepth` variable when I try to use the `\@itemdepth` counter.  I replace the variable reference with a number like 1 or 0 and the script will run.  So it seems I am doing something wrong in this reference.  I would appreciate any help that you can offer.

The relevant part of the script is as follows:  It runs as it is shown.  When the #1 is replaced with `\@itemdepth`.  It does not work.  (thanks Peter and Gonzalo for the instructions on including this.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 

\newlength{\hangparsindent}
\newcounter{hangparsindentedlevel}

\newenvironment{hangpars}[1][1]{
   \ifthenelse {#1 = 1} {
        \setlength {\hangparsindent}{0in}
        }
       {
       \setlength {\hangparsindent}{-\leftmargini}
       }

 \begin{list}{}{
   \setlength{\itemindent}{\hangparsindent}
   \setlength{\listparindent}{\hangparsindent}
   \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in} \setlength{\topsep}{0in}
   }
  \item{}
}    
{\end{list}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{hangpars}[2]
test text 1.  test text 1. test text 1.  test text 1. test text 1.  test text 1. test text 1.  test text 1. test text 1.  test text 1. 

\begin{hangpars}[1]
test text 2.  test text 2. test text 2.  test text 2. test text 2.  test text 2. test text 2.  test text 2. test text 2.  test text 2. 
\end{hangpars}

test text 3.  test text 3. test text 3.  test text 3. test text 3.  test text 3. test text 3.  test text 3. test text 3.  test text 3. 

\end{hangpars}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you include a full minimum working example including `\documentclass`.

Comment: Are you enclosing your code inside `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`? As a side note, I don't see any stepping of `\@itemdepth` in your code.

Comment: Also, it appears that you set `hangparsindent` in the tru part of the `\ifthenelse` and then set it again once you come out of the `\ifthenelse` so the **true** part has no effect.

Comment: And you declare the environment with one optional argument, but never use it.

Comment: Peter,I probably should have thought to do that the first time.  follows below.  I ripped out most of the logic to show where I was trying to put the reference to \@itemdepth.  The file below runs fine as it is.  When I replace the #1 with \@itemdepth it does not run and I get the error.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\newlength{\hangparsindent}
\newcounter{hangparsindentedlevel}
\newenvironment{hangpars}[1][1]{
\ifthenelse {#1 = 1} {
\setlength {\hangparsindent}{0in}
}
{
\setlength {\hangparsindent}{-\leftmargini}
}
\begin{list}{}{
\setlength{\itemindent}{\hangparsindent}
\setlength{\listparindent}{\hangparsindent}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in} \setlength{\topsep}{0in}
}
\item{}
}    
{\end{list}} 
\end{hangpars}

continued in next comment

Comment: \begin{document}

\begin{hangpars}[2]
test text 1.  test text 1. test text 1.  test text 1. test text 1.  test text 1. test text 1.  test text 1. test text 1.  test text 1. 

\begin{hangpars}[1]
test text 2.  test text 2. test text 2.  test text 2. test text 2.  test text 2. test text 2.  test text 2. test text 2.  test text 2. 
\end{hangpars}
 
test text 3.  test text 3. test text 3.  test text 3. test text 3.  test text 3. test text 3.  test text 3. test text 3.  test text 3. 

\end{hangpars}

\end{document}

Comment: It would be better to edit your original question to include the complete minimal working example.

Comment: Peter, The file was large and I pulled a lot of it out to show the problem I was having.  I am looking for a why to access the depth of the item indent from the newly created environment.

Comment: Gonzalo, I thought \@itemdepth was a reference to the varriable kept by the generalized list environment and as such would be indexed by the use of \item in the new environment.  Also, I ripped much of the logic out of the environment to show the part I was having trouble with.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Got this to compile, but not sure if this accomplished what you want.  The `\makeatletter` is not really needed here, but will be if you attempt to access `\@itemdepth`.  See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) for more details on this.

I added trailing `%` suppresses additional spaces.  Not all may be necessary but I learned this the hard way so it is safer to include them.  See [this question for an example of what can happen without ending lines with a percent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro).

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 

\makeatletter% Only needed to access \@itemdepth in here
\newlength{\hangparsindent} 
\newcounter{hangparsindentedlevel} 
%
\newenvironment{hangpars}[1][1]{\ifthenelse {#1 = 1} {%
    \setlength{\hangparsindent}{0in}} {%
    \setlength {\hangparsindent}{-\leftmargini}%
   } \list{}{%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\hangparsindent}%      
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\hangparsindent}%
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}% 
    \setlength{\topsep}{0in} } \item{}}%
{\endlist}%
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\begin{hangpars}[2] 
test text 1. test text 1. test text 1. test text 1. test text 1. test text 1. test text 1. test text 1. test text 1. test text 1. 
\begin{hangpars}[1] 
test text 2. test text 2. test text 2. test text 2. test text 2. test text 2. test text 2. test text 2. test text 2. test text 2. 
\end{hangpars} 
test text 3. test text 3. test text 3. test text 3. test text 3. test text 3. test text 3. test text 3. test text 3. test text 3. 
\end{hangpars}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Peter,  Thanks for showing me the \makeatletter and \makeatother commands.  It looks like they allow me to access the \@itemdepth variable.  By the way, it looks like you added a % to the end of all lines of the \newenvironment.  Mine compiled with out them.  What are they for?  Thanks again

Comment: Peter, Is there a way for me to indicate that your reply answered my question?

Comment: @Mark: Some of those `%` are probably not necessary. Try taking them out and you'll see why they are needed as you'll end up with extra spaces where you did not intend them. If this answered your question you can upvote it and select the check mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mark: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do for a description of what `\makeatletter` does. The `%` comments out the rest of the line and thus inhibits the potential inclusion of the line break as a superfluous space in the document (try `a<line break>b` and `a%<line break>b`). Also, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).