# Remove space before colorbox

Tags: spacing, color, boxes

I've made the command

```
\newcommand{\pink}[1]{\colorbox{red!20}{#1}}
```

to highlight in pink. It works fine for words and sentences, but if I want to highlight a subpart of a word, e.g.

```
laugh\pink{ing}
```

it adds a space before ing (this is for a linguistics lecture)

Is there any way to override this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, TeX language is not "free form", so there's a big difference between

```
\newcommand{\pink}[1]{
\colorbox{red!20}{#1}
}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\pink}[1]{\colorbox{red!20}{#1}}
```

In the first case two spaces are added before and after the `\colorbox`, because end-of-lines are converted into spaces and they become part of the replacement text. So your first attempt is equivalent to do

```
\newcommand{\pink}[1]{ \colorbox{red!20}{#1} }
```

and the source of the spacing is now evident.

However, there's also another catch: `\colorbox` adds a padding around the text; its thickness is controlled by the parameter `\fboxsep`.

Here is a more complex definition for taking into account a problem that will be clear from the last example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\reducedstrut}{\vrule width 0pt height .9\ht\strutbox depth .9\dp\strutbox\relax}
\newcommand{\pink}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%  
  \colorbox{red!20}{\reducedstrut#1\/}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
laugh\pink{ing}

laugh\pink{ing}

lau\pink{f}ing

lau\begingroup\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{red!20}{\reducedstrut f}\endgroup ing
\end{document}
```

I've used `\reducedstrut` in order that the colored box does not touch possible other colored boxes in the lines above or below. With `\strut`, instead of `\reducedstrut`, the colored boxes in the first two lines would merge. Finally, the "italic correction" `\/` ensures that the whole contents is covered by the pink background, as it's clear from the last two lines (the last one has the same construction, but without `\/`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've answered my own question. In the original code I'd used some new lines to make the macro more readable;

```
\newcommand{\pink}[1]{
\colorbox{red!20}{#1}
}
```

I didn't realise these would affect the final formatting.

The new version;

```
\newcommand{\pink}[1]{\colorbox{red!20}{#1}}
```

removes the gap before the colorbox. However, there is still some extra space within the colorbox before the first letter, which I'd quite like to trim.

Comment: I have gotten in the habit of adding a `%` after an open `{` as I got bit with this before. See [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro).  Took me quite some time to get the MWE.