# Visually highlighting symbolic material

Tags: math-mode, typography, highlighting

I have a diagram in which I need to indicate the difference between symbolic mathematics and English words (potentially to someone who doesn't know about it):

[image]

Colour works beautifully for making this distinction. Unfortunately, for the version that is going to go in a book, I can't use colour and have been told not to use greyscale (which was my first fallback). I've tried bold, but it looks pretty horrible and doesn't highlight the distinction terribly well:

[image]

(Also bold is bad because sometimes it has mathematical significance.)

Underlining just looks really horrible:
[image]

I would be *very* grateful for any alternative suggestions on how to visually highlight symbolic material.

Source in case it's useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{textual-colour}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{symbolic-colour}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.9}
\newcommand{\marktextual}[1]{{\color{textual-colour}#1}}
\newcommand{\marksymbolic}[1]{{\color{symbolic-colour}#1}}

\begin{framed}
\marktextual{{If}  \marksymbolic{$K \leq G$} {and} {there} {are} {inclusions} \marksymbolic{$gKg^{-1}\leq K$}  {for} {every} \marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, {then} \marksymbolic{$K \triangleleft G$}: {replacing} \marksymbolic{$g$} {by} \marksymbolic{$g^{-1}$}, {we} {have} {the} {inclusion} \marksymbolic{$g^{-1}Kg\leq K$}, {and} {this} {gives} {the} {reverse} {inclusion} \marksymbolic{$K\leq gKg^{-1}$}.}
\smallskip

\marktextual{{The} {kernel} \marksymbolic{$K$} {of} {a} {homomorphism} \marksymbolic{$f:G\rightarrow H$} {is} {a} {normal}  {subgroup}: {if} \marksymbolic{$a\in K$}, {then} \marksymbolic{$f(a)=1$}; {if} \marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, {then} \marksymbolic{$f(gag^{-1}) = f(g)f(a)f(g^{-1}) =  f(g)f(g^{-1}) = 1$}, {and} {so} \marksymbolic{$gag^{-1}\in K$}. {Hence}, \marksymbolic{$gKg^{-1}\leq K$}  {for} {all} \marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, {and} {so} \marksymbolic{$K \triangleleft G$}. {Conversely}, {we} {shall} {see} {later} {that} {every} {normal} {subgroup} {is} {the} {kernel} {of} {some} {homomorphism}.}
\end{framed}\end{document}
```

**Edit:** while I was trying to keep this short, from the comments it looks like a little more explanation of the context is necessary. The text of the book says:

"At first sight, the most striking feature of mathematical language is the way
in which it mixes material that looks as if it is drawn from a natural language
with material built up out of idiosyncratically mathematical symbols. The
distinction is illustrated in Figure 2.1."

Figure 2.1 looks like this:

[image]

Comment: For centuries math formulas have not been emphasized in any particular way other than using italics for the letters.

Comment: @egreg: I've written a book on the language of mathematics and I'm trying to explain the difference between symbolic material and words to someone who doesn't necessarily know any maths. Italicisation isn't enough, because e.g. the various operators aren't clearly indicated as being symbolic.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Would this be only for some small examples?

Comment: @ADP: then they will refuse to publish the book.

Comment: @egreg: I've added a bit more explanation to the question.

Comment: @egreg Also, saying that symbolic material is in italics would be rather dangerous as it might lead a reader to think that symbolic material is _always_ in italics (which is not the case).

Comment: @Mohan Perhaps a light grey background?

Comment: I'd suggest to typeset the non-symbolic part in a lighter grey to make the symbolic part stick out without resorting to bold. I'd also use the caption to say something like "symbols are typeset traditionally in italics. The non-symbolic parts have been additionally typeset here in a lighter color for emphasis."

Comment: @Christian Lindig: That's what I meant by `have been told not to use greyscale'... I tried that and was told it wouldn't show up well in the book.

Comment: What about using other fonts? For example, sans serif math fonts or tt math fonts or even Euler fonts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A solution with `hf-tikz` (requires two compilation runs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\hfsetbordercolor{white}
\definecolor{vlgray}{rgb}{0.87 0.87 0.87}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{highlight}
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
\stepcounter{highlight}\tikzmarkin{\thehighlight}(0.04,-0.1)(-0.04,0.3)#1\tikzmarkend{\thehighlight}%
}

\newcommand{\exampletext}{%
  If \highlight{$K \leq G$} and there are inclusions \highlight{$gKg^{-1}\leq K$} 
  for every \highlight{$g\in G$}, then \highlight{$K \triangleleft G$}: replacing 
  \highlight{$g$} by \highlight{$g^{-1}$}, we have the inclusion 
  \highlight{$g^{-1}Kg\leq K$}, and this gives the reverse inclusion 
  \highlight{$K\leq gKg^{-1}$}.

  The kernel \highlight{$K$} of a homomorphism \highlight{$f:G\rightarrow H$} is a 
  normal  subgroup: if \highlight{$a\in K$}, then \highlight{$f(a)=1$}; if 
  \highlight{$g\in G$}, then 
  \highlight{$f(gag^{-1}) = f(g)f(a)f(g^{-1}) =$}\penalty\relpenalty
  \highlight{$ f(g)f(g^{-1}) = 1$},
  and so \highlight{$gag^{-1}\in K$}. Hence, \highlight{$gKg^{-1}\leq K$} for all 
  \highlight{$g\in G$}, and so \highlight{$K \triangleleft G$}. Conversely, 
  we shall see later that every normal subgroup is the kernel of some homomorphism.}

\begin{document}
\hfsetfillcolor{white}
\begin{framed}
\exampletext
\end{framed}

\hfsetfillcolor{vlgray}
\begin{framed}
\exampletext
\end{framed}

Applied to \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88977/putting-a-coloured-background-behind-text-without-adding-whitespace}{Putting a coloured background behind text without adding whitespace}:

Lorem ipsum \highlight{dolor} sit amet, \highlight{consectetuer} adipiscing elit, sed diam 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: The second use is a bit inappropriate, thus I didn't answered directly to that question.

Answer (score 15):

Without using color for the formulas or a gray background, I don't see any good way for distinguishing between text and formulas. Boxing the formulas seems out of the question because it's really too heavy; underlining is, as you say, horrible.

A way out might be to present the same paragraphs typeset twice: one with blanks in place of the formulas, so by comparing the two images one can see what you're referring to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,calc}

\newcommand{\exampletext}{%
  If \marksymbolic{$K \leq G$} and there are inclusions \marksymbolic{$gKg^{-1}\leq K$} 
  for every \marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, then \marksymbolic{$K \triangleleft G$}: replacing 
  \marksymbolic{$g$} by \marksymbolic{$g^{-1}$}, we have the inclusion 
  \marksymbolic{$g^{-1}Kg\leq K$}, and this gives the reverse inclusion 
  \marksymbolic{$K\leq gKg^{-1}$}.

  The kernel \marksymbolic{$K$} of a homomorphism \marksymbolic{$f:G\rightarrow H$} is a 
  normal  subgroup: if \marksymbolic{$a\in K$}, then \marksymbolic{$f(a)=1$}; if 
  \marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, then 
  \marksymbolic{$f(gag^{-1}) = f(g)f(a)f(g^{-1}) =$}\penalty\relpenalty
  \marksymbolic{$ f(g)f(g^{-1}) = 1$},
  and so \marksymbolic{$gag^{-1}\in K$}. Hence, \marksymbolic{$gKg^{-1}\leq K$} for all 
  \marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, and so \marksymbolic{$K \triangleleft G$}. Conversely, 
  we shall see later that every normal subgroup is the kernel of some homomorphism.}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\providecommand{\marksymbolic}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}]{\hrulefill}}
\exampletext
\end{framed}

\begin{framed}
\providecommand{\marksymbolic}[1]{\mbox{#1}}
\exampletext
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the same with

```
\providecommand{\marksymbolic}[1]{{\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox[gray]{0.9}{#1}}}
```

[image]

Comment: In case anyone else tries this: the `reducedstrut` from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74459/remove-space-before-colorbox makes the the height of the great boxes a little more consistent.

Answer (score 8):

The advise of "*not to use greyscale*" probably can be extended to the background, and personally I think so many gray boxes breaks the reading flow.

My proposal is use a clearly different fonts for the math and text modes, if needed, adjusting the size of math mode to look similar to text mode. Although one might think a higher size would highlight also the math mode, may be is only less readable. For example, for me with `lxfonts` look better a smaller font size:

[image: MWe2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lxfonts} 
\usepackage{framed}
\newcommand{\marksymbolic}[1]{{\footnotesize #1}}
\begin{document}
\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}
\begin{framed}
If 
\marksymbolic{$K \leq G$} and there are inclusions 
\marksymbolic{$gKg^{-1}\leq K$} for every 
\marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, then 
\marksymbolic{$K \triangleleft G$}: replacing 
\marksymbolic{$g$} by 
\marksymbolic{$g^{-1}$}, we have the inclusion 
\marksymbolic{$g^{-1}Kg\leq K$}, and this gives the reverse inclusion
\marksymbolic{$K\leq gKg^{-1}$}.

The kernel 
\marksymbolic{$K$} of a homomorphism 
\marksymbolic{$f:G\rightarrow H$} is a normal subgroup: if 
\marksymbolic{$a\in K$}, then 
\marksymbolic{$f(a)=1$}; if 
\marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, then 
\marksymbolic{$f(gag^{-1}) = f(g)f(a)f(g^{-1}) =  f(g)f(g^{-1}) = 1$}, and so 
\marksymbolic{$gag^{-1}\in K$}. Hence, 
\marksymbolic{$gKg^{-1}\leq K$}  for all 
\marksymbolic{$g\in G$}, and so 
\marksymbolic{$K \triangleleft G$}. 
Conversely, we shall see later that every normal subgroup is the kernel of some homomorphism.
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: from your code I can not obtain result as you show in your answer. Ordinary text is in the same, upright fonts as math expression. Please, can you check again if something is missing in your code?

Comment: @Zarko, I am sure that the former code worked in 2011, but for some reason is not longer true.  I changed the approach to use lxfonts only for  math mode, but I cleaned also the unnecessary macros and brackets of the MWE in the question, but the result is the same as showed the image.

Comment: Dear @Fran, now work as advertised :-).  And markup now is simpler! Eh, in three yeaers also in LaTeX many things changed. Thank you very much.