# Font used for special characters in listings

Tags: fonts, listings, colorbox

I'm trying to highlight code fragments in the `listings` environment. To do this, I'm using a colorbox with no padding as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74469/113805):

```
\newcommand{\reducedstrut}{\vrule width 0pt height .9\ht\strutbox depth .9\dp\strutbox\relax}
\newcommand{\hlight}[1]{\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{yellow}{\reducedstrut#1\/}\endgroup}
```

The listings are set up to syntax highlight C code and use `ttfamily` as the font:

```
\lstset{ 
    language=C, 
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, 
    breakatwhitespace=true, 
    columns=fullflexible,
    tabsize=2,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
}
```

Now, if I create a `lstlisting`, the special characters contained therein are displayed in `ttfamily`:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
int main() {
    printf("\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image: example listing]

However, if I highlight the code, special characters, (`{`, `}` and `\` in the example below) are displayed using the default latex font:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
(*@\hlight{\textbf{int main() \{}}@*)
    (*@\hlight{printf("\textbackslash n");}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image: example listing 2]

How do I define `\hlight` so that the font remains the same in the inner `colorbox`?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\lstset{ 
    language=C, 
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, 
    breakatwhitespace=true, 
    columns=fullflexible,
    tabsize=2,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
}
\newcommand{\reducedstrut}{\vrule width 0pt height .9\ht\strutbox depth .9\dp\strutbox\relax}
\newcommand{\hlight}[1]{\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{yellow}{\reducedstrut#1\/}\endgroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int main() {
    printf("\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
(*@\hlight{\textbf{int main() \{}}@*)
    (*@\hlight{printf("\textbackslash n");}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Adding the package fixed the problem! Could you please add this as an answer (possibly with an explanation) so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the default OT1 encoding, the commands `\{`, `\}` and `\textbackslash` take the corresponding character from the math font even if the context is typewriter type. One might try and fix this, but it's simpler to use the `T1` encoding.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
    language=C, 
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, 
    breakatwhitespace=true, 
    columns=fullflexible,
    tabsize=2,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
}
\newcommand{\reducedstrut}{\vrule width 0pt height .9\ht\strutbox depth .9\dp\strutbox\relax}
\newcommand{\hlight}[1]{\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{yellow}{\reducedstrut#1\/}\endgroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
int main() {
    printf("\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
(*@\hlight{\textbf{int main() \{}}@*)
    (*@\hlight{printf("\textbackslash n");}@*)
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this without relying on T1 `fontenc`? The submission instructions for paper do not allow me to use the T1 `fontenc` package and they recommend using `CM super` instead.

Comment: @peteykun I think you're misunderstanding the instructions. There's no CM super package and those fonts are used precisely when T1 is passed to fontenc.