# How to remove indents for the initial list but indent all nested lists?

Tags: environments, indentation, margins, enumitem

I'm trying to use `enumitem` to modify my lists so that they're flush to the left side of the paper but so that any nested lists are properly indented.

This is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{nolistsep}
    \newenvironment{notes}
        {\begin{itemize}[label=,leftmargin=0em,labelindent=1cm]\ignorespaces}
        {\end{itemize}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
\begin{notes}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
        \begin{notes}
            \item item 2.a
            \item item 2.b
        \end{notes}
\end{notes}

\end{document}
```

It ends up looking like this:

```
item 1
item 2
item 2.a
item 2.b
```

How can I modify it so it looks like this?

```
item 1
item 2
    item 2.a
    item 2.b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can us adjust the `\leftmargin` once you are inside the `notes` list:

```
    \newcommand{\LeftMargin}{0em}%
    \newenvironment{notes}{%
         \begin{itemize}[label=,leftmargin=\LeftMargin,labelindent=1cm]%
          \renewcommand*{\LeftMargin}{1cm}%
          \ignorespaces%
    }{%
        \end{itemize}%
        \ignorespacesafterend%
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Just out of curiosity, why do you append the % symbol to the end of each of your lines?

Comment: @Michael0x2a: The percent signs here are intended to suppress a spurious space in the output. I learned the hard way as per [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577), so I tend to add them always. BUT, before you start doing that you should also see [When is it harmful to add percent character at end of lines in a \newcommand, or similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34844) as there are cases where you don't want to do that.