# Macro to insert formatted text: def, let or what?

Tags: macros

I want to insert formatting text with a single command (I know the text beforehand):

```
 {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}\
```

How do I "bind" it to a macro? I tried:

```
 \def\sol#0 {{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}}
 \let\sol {{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}}
```

Both give errors. I'm sure I'm missing something trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `\def` for these kinds of things, just use `\newcommand` when using LaTeX:

```
\newcommand*\sol{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}}
```

`\def` and `\let` are pure TeX commands, it is recommended to use the LaTeX equivalent.
In your case the proper way to use `\def` would be:

```
\def\sol{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}}
```

`\let` lets you copy a command, for example:

```
\let\solcopy\sol
```

Now you could change `\sol` with `\renewcommand`.

Also see:

- [Wikibooks TeX/def](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/def)
- [Wikibooks TeX/let](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/let)
- [Wikibooks LaTeX/Customizing LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX) (more information on `\newcommand`).

Answer (score 2):

Both your invocations of `\def` and `\let` are flawed.  For the first, to define a macro with no arguments, you just write `\def\sol{...}`, without `#0`: the terms `#n` don't mean "this macro has this many arguments", but rather, "this is the n'th argument".  So with one argument you would use `\def\sol#1{...}`, with two `\def\sol#1#2{...}`, and so on.  It is also possible to intersperse other stuff between the arguments to create a context for the macro, but that's not relevant here.

For the second, `\let` defines a macro name to be equal to *one* other token, not a brace group.  So what you wrote,

```
\let\sol {{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}}
```

is the same as writing something with the following more obvious intent:

```
\let\sol {
{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}}
```

meaning that `\sol` becomes a left brace and then TeX tries to process the rest, which has an excess right brace (since the other member of its pair just got eaten by `\let`).  And that's your error.

That said, as Silex wrote, it's best to just use `\newcommand`; `\def` and `\let` are too primitive for a high-level document.  So:

```
\newcommand\sol{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}}
```

As a side note, you should omit the space you put after `\def` and `\let`; although it's harmless here, unnecessary spaces in TeX *will* lead to problems (see [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro/20579#20579)).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found it:

```
\newcommand\sol{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}Решение}\par}
```