# If.. then else and flipping a variable

Tags: etoolbox, ifthenelse

I am trying to write a template to automatically load files inside directories formatted in a certain way, and I want to print something every time a new file is found in a directory previously empty.

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}


\foreach \Year in {2016,...,2020}
{
  \newtoggle{mytoggle}
  \toggletrue{mytoggle}

  \foreach \Month in {Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}
  {   \foreach \Day in {1,...,31}
    { \IfFileExists{\Year/\Month/\Day}
      {
        \iftoggle{mytoggle}{
          \togglefalse{mytoggle}
          true
        }{
          false
        }

        \input{\Year/\Month/\Day.tex}
      }
    }
  }
}
\end{document}
```

I would expect that the `true` branch is called only once, however it is called every time. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Using `\newtoggle` in the loop over and over again looks weird

Comment: You can use `\InputIfFileExists` as well, this combines the test for the existince of the file and the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `\foreach` forms a group, thus you need to apply `\global` before a `\toggletrue` or `\togglefalse` within a `\foreach`.

Result of the MEW below *without* the `\global`

[image]

and *with* the `\global`:

[image]

### Notes:

- No need to declare the `\newtoggle` within the `\foreach`.
- Be careful of the space following the `foreach {`  as this can add up. See [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro).
- Also, with macros such as `\IfFileExists`, make sure that you cover *both* the true and false case. Use `{}` for the case that you don't need anything executed.  This was missing in the code you provided.
- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)
  was used to set up a file to read for this test case.
  It is not needed in you actual use case.  Also, to simplify the MWE, the file naming was altered to not require additional directories.

### Code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{2016-Mar-24.tex}
content for file 2016-Mar-24\par
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{2016-Jul-10.tex}
content for file 2016-Jul-10\par
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{2017-Dec-31.tex}
content for file 2017-Dec-31\par
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{mytoggle}

\begin{document}
\foreach \Year in {2016,...,2020} {%
  \global\toggletrue{mytoggle}%
  %
  \foreach \Month in {Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec} {%   
      \foreach \Day in {1,...,31} {%
       \IfFileExists{\Year-\Month-\Day.tex}{%
            \iftoggle{mytoggle}{%
                true
                \global\togglefalse{mytoggle}%
            }{%
                false
                \global\toggletrue{mytoggle}%
            }%
            \input{\Year-\Month-\Day.tex}
      }{}%
    }% foreach \Day
  }% foreach \Month
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to build a file name from the input stream, the primitive `\input` absorbs and expands tokens until finding an unexpandable token that can't be interpreted as being part of a file name (implementation dependent); so `\input{\Year/\Month/\Day}` does the same as the indirect path with `\edef` you propose.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing that out and have removed that comment regarding an `\edef`. I know I have had issues with similar use of file names but perhaps it was not with `\input`.

Comment: It works perfectly well and for providing all the explanations needed!