# How to prevent line break before quotation mark when using a different font in quotation

Tags: fonts, line-breaking

I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\french[1]{\!\!
  \fontfamily{jkplkvos}\selectfont
  #1
  \fontfamily{\familydefault}\selectfont \!\!}

\begin{document}

\qquad The closest Modern French equivalent to the Middle French word
``\french{par}'' is ``par''.

\end{document}
```

How do I prevent the line break between \french{par} and ''?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Try adding a `%` after the `#1` in the definition of `\french`.  Not sure why you have the `\!\!`, but to get things to look nice you and keep the `\!\!` using `#1~%` seems to work.

Comment: I have the `\!\!` because otherwise there is a big space between the quotes and what they enclose.

Comment: Ah, getting rid of the `\!\!` and adding `%` after every line in the definition of `\french` fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: In the case: eliminate all four of the `\!`, and use `\newcommand\french[1]{%`, `\fontfamily{jkplkvos}\selectfont%`, `#1%` and `\fontfamily{\familydefault}\selectfont}`.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminating the `\!` and adding `%` to eliminate the spurious spaces yields:

[image]

### References:

- [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\french[1]{%
  \fontfamily{jkplkvos}\selectfont
  #1%
  \fontfamily{\familydefault}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\qquad The closest Modern French equivalent to the Middle French word
``\french{par}'' is ``par''.

\end{document}
```