# tikz draw on table image clipped in standalone documentclass

Tags: tables, standalone, annotations

I always think standalone will display my drawings at center but below example seems clipped (the red lines).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{>=latex} 
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,baseline]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,
    minimum width=.5cm,align=center,text depth=.25ex,outer sep=1.5pt]
\tikzstyle{every path}+=[very thick]

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz \node (#1) {#2};}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c|>{\bfseries}c|}
    \toprule
    \hline
 \tikzmark{m00}{Number} & \tikzmark{m01}{Name} \\ \hline
  \tikzmark{m10}{0} & \tikzmark{m11}{Jack} \\ \hline
  \tikzmark{m20}{1} & \tikzmark{m21}{Mary} \\ \hline
  \tikzmark{m30}{2} & \tikzmark{m31}{John} \\ \hline
  \tikzmark{m40}{3} & \tikzmark{m41}{Alice} \\ \hline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\coordinate (P) at ([xshift=20pt]m21.east);
\draw[red] (m11.east) -| (P);
\draw[->,red] (P) |- (m21.east);
\draw[red] (m31.east) -| (P);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
How should I fix it?

Comment: The size of the standalone is the size of the tabular.  Overlay has no size. One solution is to place the tabular inside a somewhat wider minipage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a horizontal space at the end of the `tabular`. Below I added `\hspace*{15pt}` which yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- You had several supurious spaces in your code which results in additional spacing in the output. I removed those. For an extreme case see [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro).
- You should use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle`: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{>=latex}%
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,baseline]%
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,
    minimum width=.5cm,align=center,text depth=.25ex,outer sep=1.5pt]%
\tikzstyle{every path}+=[very thick]%
%
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz \node (#1) {#2};}%
%
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c|>{\bfseries}c|}
    \toprule
    \hline
  \tikzmark{m00}{Number} & \tikzmark{m01}{Name} \\ \hline
  \tikzmark{m10}{0} & \tikzmark{m11}{Jack} \\ \hline
  \tikzmark{m20}{1} & \tikzmark{m21}{Mary} \\ \hline
  \tikzmark{m30}{2} & \tikzmark{m31}{John} \\ \hline
  \tikzmark{m40}{3} & \tikzmark{m41}{Alice} \\ \hline
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \coordinate (P) at ([xshift=20pt]m21.east);
    \draw[red] (m11.east) -| (P);
    \draw[->,red] (P) |- (m21.east);
    \draw[red] (m31.east) -| (P);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace*{15pt}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, it works fine. BTW, why we need to add a % after each command?

Comment: @lucky1928:  Most of them result in extra spacing that is usually unwanted.  See the link provided in the _Notes_ section.