# White space between document edge and background

Tags: backgrounds

I'm using a page-sized background image for my document to get a nice looking company page. However, it does not perfectly align to the left, but is slightly shifted, resulting in an ugly white edge on the left side (see attached image). What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=20mm, bottom=25mm, left=20mm, right=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
    \put(0, 0){
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{
            \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{background_pic}
            \vfill
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
Here is some text
\end{document}
```

Grey is my editor background, blue is my actual `background_pic`, and the white line at the document is what is annoying me.

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing some `%` at the end of the lines. So lines ending in `{` should be `{%` and some ending in `}` should be `}%`. Just using `\put(0, 0){%` may be sufficient but if not, try the others. For reference see [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20577/4301) and [When is it harmful to add percent character at end of lines in a \newcommand, or similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34844/4301).

Comment: That's it! Could you post this as an answer, and, maybe, explain a bit what that `%` means? I always this is to comment out parts of the code, but in those cases it is to tell the compiler that the command is going on in the next line?

Comment: See the links in Peter's answer. Basically a line break counts as a space, so the percent sign is to remove that space.